# Angular 2 Child component to check parent component

Tags: angular, angular2-components

what I want to achieve is different behavior of a component based on which component is its parent component. So in the following two situations the child would behave slightly different.

example A

```
<parent-a>
<child></child>
</parent-a>
```

example B

```
<parent-b>
<child></child>
</parent-b>
```

I tried to do the following

```
constructor(
    el: ElementRef) {
      this.el = el; 
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const hostElem = this.el.nativeElement;
    console.log(hostElem);
    console.log(hostElem.children);
    console.log(hostElem.parentNode);
  }
```

eventhough ngAfterViewInit is a bit late for me, I still got null on the parentNode

Is there any way to achieve something like that?

Comment: That's not how it should work. Instead, pass an input from the parent to the child to tell it how to behave.

Comment: yeah, it kind of already do that (with a service) but what if the parent is not the one I expect? (i am building an Api basically). I basically want to give error/warnings with a list of the expected parent nodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the actual component (and not the node element) you can use the injector.

```
constructor(private parentB: ParentBComponent){
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.parentB.someMethod()
}
```

Note that you have `parent-a` and `parent-b`, if you want to be able to inject any, define a base component and have both `parent-a` and `parent-b` inherit from it.

You can make it optional, you can use the `Optional` decorator:

```
constructor(@Optional() private parentB?: ParentBComponent){
}
```

Comment: and if none is present, I can throw an error I guess. that might do. Ill try it before accepting it though ;)

Comment: Meaning if it is not in the context of that parent? In that case the member `parentB` will be undefined.

Comment: In general it is strongly not recommended to use html elements (parentNode etc.), try to do the work within the framework and use the Renderer for updates

Comment: I don't want to update anything. My problem is that, in the case of the parent not being a or b, to write a warning and not to execute any functionallity

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked like a charm, the thing is that I don't really need to use the parent components, in any way. I Just want to know if they are there, and if not I can throw an error.

Comment: What if the child component is inside an *ngIf and is not created until the condition is true? Then the component will be undefined in the ngAfterViewInit of the parent component, isnt it? Just to take it into account.